Opening DevTools with Angular 17 project and SourceMap active makes Chrome freeze/lag
I started a new project to update an old project that was running and being updated from Angular 6, its full of old code and its not big enough to have year of refactoring.
While there was low amount of files, nothing much happened.
But at some point, every time i have DevTools open i think im using Chrome by taking photos. Sometimes while changing tabs, the delay is like 8 to 10 seconds. The moment i close DevTools, the lag is gone.
With the current angular 14 application, full of components, there is no problem. Just the new project.
At the same time, while using Firefox, i have 0 problems.
Chrome version: 123.0.6312.106
Firefox version: 124.0.2
There is any configuration in Chrome to solve this?
Is this a Chrome problem?
Is this an Angular problem?
Im just hopeless, i need to use Chrome as it is the only browser we are officially supporting (small company).
